# How to set Invitation Request Connection Timeout with XMPPFramework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

How can I set the timeout in XMPP? As far as I searched I found there are two timeouts.

> 1. Timeout during which App tries to make connection with Server. This timeout is configurable:

```
[_xmppStream connectWithTimeout:kTimeOutForChat error:&error]
```

> 2. Timeout at which `XMPPStream` checks for invitation approval/Decline after connection with `Spark` is in Library File.

I'm searching for solutions to allow me to configure second timeout without modifying the library.

```
 FileName : XMPPStream.m
 #define TIMEOUT_XMPP_READ_STREAM   -1
```

I want this `-1` to `40`. I don't want to edit the Library file. Is there any way I can set without modifying the Library?

**EDIT:** Code Near TimeOut Macro

```
  /**
  * Seeing a return statements within an inner block
  * can sometimes be mistaken for a return point of the enclosing method.
   * This makes inline blocks a bit easier to read.
   **/
   #define return_from_block  return

  // Define the timeouts (in seconds) for retreiving various parts of the XML stream
  #define TIMEOUT_XMPP_WRITE         -1
  #define TIMEOUT_XMPP_READ_START    10
  #define TIMEOUT_XMPP_READ_STREAM   40

 // Define the tags we'll use to differentiate what it is we're currently reading or writing
 #define TAG_XMPP_READ_START         100
 #define TAG_XMPP_READ_STREAM        101
 #define TAG_XMPP_WRITE_START        200
 #define TAG_XMPP_WRITE_STOP         201
 #define TAG_XMPP_WRITE_STREAM       202
 #define TAG_XMPP_WRITE_RECEIPT      203

 // Define the timeouts (in seconds) for SRV
```

Comment: Show a bit more of the code around the define, is there an if statement before it? Is the library pre-built or are you building it?

Comment: @Wain this library is prebuild. I am installing it Via Cocoa Pod. here is the link of Libray and I have updated my question showin more code. https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework

Comment: doesn't look like it's prebuilt, but it also isn't going to be easy to change with the preprocessor. i'd suggest just forking the project and editing it slightly...

Comment: yes I was thinking to do the same.. But thought may be some other solution exist or I am unable to get the method name for doing this. anyways thanks for solution :) @Wain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code had an `#ifdef` to check if the define already existed then you could use the preprocessor to define the value you want. But, it doesn't, so I can't think of an easy was to use the preprocessor to replace it and keep it compilable.

The simplest solution is just to fork the project and maintain a small change. This should be a low cost solution as your change will be limited to a single line and merging upstream changes should (generally) be automatic.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-define the preprocessor macro in your app.

```
#undef  TIMEOUT_XMPP_WRITE
#define TIMEOUT_XMPP_WRITE 40
```

This might cause more confusion with your developers, and I would use this with caution.

Comment: where should I define this Macro. In My ChatViewController...Or somewhere else. I tried it but it doesn't work :( @jal

Comment: @RahulMishra what happens if you redefine the macro just before you use it?  Can you `NSLog` to verify that the value has in fact changed to 40?

Comment: I am continuous getting chat invitation request till 1min 6 sec.

Comment: @RahulMishra that doesn't make sense.  You should be able to redefine the `#define` no problem.  Is the library compiled before integration with your app?